# what's the difference of db.mydb.find({tag:'java'}).count() and db.mydb.count({tag:'java'}) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm need to count a lot of documents (30 M) with a criteria fast in mondodb

what's the difference of db.mydb.find({tag:'java'}).count() and db.mydb.count({tag:'java'})

it's one faster than the other?

I have and index on tag.

Thanks,

Federico.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a little trick to see what MongoDB commands do under the hood:

```
> 
> db.mydb.count
function (x) {
    return this.find(x).count();
}
>
> db.mydb.find().count
function (applySkipLimit) {
    var cmd = {count:this._collection.getName()};
    if (this._query) {
        if (this._special) {
            cmd.query = this._query.query;
        } else {
            cmd.query = this._query;
        }
    }
    cmd.fields = this._fields || {};
    if (applySkipLimit) {
        if (this._limit) {
            cmd.limit = this._limit;
        }
        if (this._skip) {
            cmd.skip = this._skip;
        }
    }
    var res = this._db.runCommand(cmd);
    if (res && res.n != null) {
        return res.n;
    }
    throw "count failed: " + tojson(res);
}
```

So yes, you can see that `collection.count` is just a wrapper around `collection.find().count`

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. MongoDB looks at all of the query parameters as a single object. In this case, count is a 'cursor method' which means it is executed on the server side. See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying

Comment: Yep, they are the same. It is just a convenience method on the cursor.